# В Python индекс выходит за границы диапазона при переборе

Tags: python, циклы, while, indexerror

Перебираю циклом **while** список `x_j_list`, увеличивая каждый раз индекс `point_elem_j` на единицу. При этом добавляю в список `parameters_list` новое значение `poly_n`.

Однако получаю ошибку

> IndexError: list index out of range

Она возникает в строке `poly_n = x_j_list[point_elem_j] - x_col_list[0]`.

На моем полном примере я успеваю пройти 21 итерацию (по количеству элементов в списке`x_j_list`), но не получается рассчитать для списка `parameters_list` финальное, 21-е, значение `poly_n`.

В чем проблема?

Код:

```
import numpy as np

x_i_list = [(0.1*np.pi*i) for i in range(0, 11)]
x_j_list = [(0.05*np.pi*j) for j in range(0, 21)]
order = 4
x_col_list = [0.0, 0.3141592653589793, 0.6283185307179586, 0.9424777960769379]


point_elem_j = 0
# пока индекс в сетке x_j_list не достигл длины данного списка: 
while point_elem_j <= len(x_j_list):

    poly_n = x_j_list[point_elem_j] - x_col_list[0] # считаем первый элемент
    parameters_list = [poly_n]
    for args, elems in enumerate(x_col_list[1:]):
        poly_n = (x_j_list[point_elem_j] - elems) * poly_n # считаем второй и последующие элементы
        parameters_list.append(poly_n)
        
    point_elem_j += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вот в этой строке `while point_elem_j <= len(x_j_list):`

вы задаете условие, что переменная `point_elem_j` может достичь значения, равного `len(x_j_list)`, а при индексации длиной списка всегда будет возникать `IndexError` по очевидным причинам (индексация с нуля).

Вот пример, чтобы было понятнее:

Пусть длина списка = 1

```
a = [100]
```

и вы хотите проиндексироваться по элементу с индексом равным длине списка, то есть 1, очевидно, что раз в списке один элемент, то у этого элемента индекс будет 0, а не 1.

Поэтому, во избежание таких ошибок, надо знать, что последний элемент списка всегда имеет индекс `len(a) - 1`:

```
x = len(a) # 1
print(a[x]) # -> IndexError
print(a[len(a) - 1]) # -> 100
```

Comment: Действительно, спасибо: это на самом деле помогло! Убрал из условия знак `=`, оставив `<`.

Comment: @AlexKazantsev рад, что смог помочь. Успехов!